# "no implicit conversion of Array into String"

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view-components

please I just developed a game in Ruby on Rails, and I am about to deploy it. Everything works fine in the development stage but keeps on getting "ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Array into String):" in the deployment environment.
The error pointed me to a particular line of code which is,

```
def passcode
  JSON.parse(game.passcode)
end
```

This is the output of my object before the JSON.parse;

```
"[\"ORANGE\", \"YELLOW\", \"PURPLE\", \"GREEN\"]"
```

The method above output;

```
["ORANGE", "YELLOW", "PURPLE", "GREEN"]
```

The passcode was used to get the game outcome after the player won or lost the game.

```
def game_outcome
 if !attempts.empty? && passcode == last_attempt
  return "Congratulations!"
 elsif attempts.size == guesses.size && passcode != last_attempt
  return "Sorry, you've lost! It was a bit difficult"
 end
end
```

I have tried to see the output of the method on my local machine and it outputs an array, which I think it's the right thing

I will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: How or where is `passcode` used? (check the other lines in the error's backtrace) Maybe it is supposed to be a string. Solely based on its name, I would also expect a "passcode" (singular) to be a string rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will edit my question and add where the passcode method is used. Though I named the method a passcode because it's an array.

Comment: From the code it seems that `attempts` is an array / collection and `last_attempt` is a string / element of that collection. If so, `passcode` would be a string, too. (rather than an array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game.passcode is returning an array, which causing the issue. Can you share from where this method is being called.
or

Your can try converting to json to avoid this errors like

```
def passcode
  obj = game.passcode.is_a?(Array) ? game.passcode.to_json : game.passcode
  JSON.parse(obj)
end
```

or else you can also directly return the game.passcode if it is an array else you can parse Json.

Hope this will resovle ur issue

Comment: Thank you for the response. The game.passcode outputs a string and not an array                                 
    "[\"ORANGE\", \"YELLOW\", \"PURPLE\", \"GREEN\"]"